# Idiomatic way to destructure commands in Clojure

Tags: clojure, pattern-matching, record, idioms, destructuring

Here's some code I wrote, using [clojure.core.match](https://github.com/clojure/core.match/wiki/Overview), which performs a pretty common programming task. A function takes some "commands" (or "objects", "records", or whatever you prefer to call them), has to do something different with each type, and has to destructure them to figure out exactly what to do, and different command types might have to be destructured differently:

```
(defn action->edits [g action]
  "Returns vector of edits needed to perform action in graph g."
  (match action
    [:boost from to]
      [[:add-edge from to 1.0]]
    [:retract from to]
      [[:remove-edge from to]]
    [:normalize from to]       ; a change has just been made to from->to 
      (map (fn [that] [:remove-edge from that])
           (successors-except g from to))
    [:recip-normalize to from] ; a change has just been made to from->to
      []
    [:reduce-to-unofficial from to competitor]
      [[:remove-edge from to] (make-competitive-edge from competitor]))
```

I'm mostly imitating the way people commonly use the [pmatch](https://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-pub/lkuper/c311/_media/pmatch.pdf) macro in Scheme. I'd like to know what's the idiomatic way to do this in Clojure.

Here's what I like about the above code:

- It's *very* readable.
- It was effortless to write.

Here's what I don't like:

- Accessing the `from` and `to` fields from anywhere but inside a `match` macro is extremely unreadable and error-prone. For example, to extract the `from` element from most of the action vectors, you write `(action 1)`. That code will break if I ever add a new action, and it breaks right now on `:recip-normalize`.
- The code generated by `match` is inefficient: it searches by repeatedly throwing and catching exceptions. It doesn't just generate a big nested `if`.

I experimented a little with representing the commands as maps, but it seemed to get verbose, and the name of the command doesn't stand out well, greatly reducing readability:

```
  (match action
    {:action :boost :from from :to to}
      [{:edit :add-edge :from from :to to :weight 1.0}]
    {:action :retract :from from :to to}
      [{:edit :remove-edge :from from :to to}]
    . . .)
```

Probably future versions of `match` will generate better code, but the poor code generated now (and lack of support for records) suggests that in Clojure, people have been handling this kind of thing happily for years without `match`. So how *do* you do this kind of thing in Clojure?

Comment: why not `(defn action->edits [g [action f t]]` and `(condp = action :boost "boosting"`, or am I missing something ? - In other words why not destructure the fn params in the first place ?

Comment: @birdspider Thanks, `condp` might be just what I need! I've only been using Clojure for a couple days, hence my writing "Scheme in Clojure". Post an answer! BTW, it appears that in my example, all the records have the same two parameters. Usually when I do this kind of thing, they vary. I'll modify the example right now because I'm interested in the idiom for how you destructure variant records—but in my actual code, I'll exploit the common pattern just as you suggested. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would utilize clojure's build-in [destructuring facilities](http://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#binding-forms), since I do not see a requirement for core.match here - but I might be missing something.

For example:

```
(defn action->edits [g [action from to]]
  (condp = action
    :boost "boosting"
    :retract "retracting"
    :normalize-ksp-style (recur g [:boost from to])
    nil))

(action->edits 2 [:normalize-ksp-style 1 2]) 
;=> "boosting"
```

Comment: Thanks—this might be just what this Clojure noob needed. Three questions: 1) What is "ksp style"? ([This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerbal_Space_Program)?) 2) Is there an easy way to destructure different actions if they have different parameters? 3) How would you usually access the `from` and `to` fields of an action elsewhere in the code? `(action 1)` and `(action 2)`, always destructure, better to use a map than a vector, something else?

Comment: @BenKovitz 1) yeah ! 1 was just testing ksp 1.1prerelease and your question with boosting comes up - couldn't resist. 2) well you can destructure on (map) keys (see the link I provided - scroll down), 3) well readability-wise why not in a `(let [ [a f t] action ]` - but I guess there is no hard rule, (except performance, then you want `defrecord`s)